# horizontal scrolling bar at top of html

Tags: html, scrollbar

i've seen a lot of question about the scrollbar at top of an div. But is it also possible to have the scrollbar at top of your page(body). And if it's possible, how?

much thanks!

Comment: One way is to use custom scroll bars. Technically you can place them wherever you want. However, users are used to see vertical scroll bar on the right and horizontal one at the bottom of the content. Better you avoid surprises!

Comment: Refresh the page, the scrollbar is at the top of the document. You're welcome. If you need an answer, be clear please.

Comment: @enguerranws your comment isn't nearly as clear as the question.

Comment: Feel free to explain what he tried to say.

Comment: @enguerranws I don't know how to reword "is it also possible to have the scrollbar at top of your page(body)." so that it's clearer. Possibly you're confusing the words "scrollbar" and "thumb".

Comment: @MrLister Maybe it's clearer for you, not for me. I don't even know why that post hasn't been closed: no context, no code, unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The position (and, indeed, styling) of the scrollbars for the viewport is a matter for the browser, and can't be controlled with HTML.

However, it might be better to just enclose your whole page in a `div`.

Answer (score 0):

The browser displays scrollbars when your browser window is small than the size of web-page.It will happen only when you specify the size of webpage or div in pixels.

```
It is possible to place the scrollbar at the top.
```

[Follow this link for demo](http://aburt.com/topscrollbar/)